# GWT CellList or Cell Table?

Tags: java, gwt, widget

I want to display some data that relates to products like the ebay styles having some info about the product in rows where the user can click on the products. which is the best widget to use in gwt for this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly advise you [GWT Cell Table](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r9085/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html) and it has many advantages over cell list and flextable both event and handlers. Here is [Cell Table example](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a FlexTable - it can hold any widget.